# Do we pay for disks with reserved state in azure?

Tags: azure, cloud

A disk with a reserved state means that this disk is attached to a stopped (deallocated) virtual machine. I have a doubt if I'm being charged for that disk?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will be charged for a disk in a reserved state. For you to not be charged, you need to delete the disk.

We have faced a similar problem. The azure billing team confirmed us that we will be charged as long as the disk is available under resources.